# Exercise on open and closed sets

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

Consider $\Bbb R^2$ with the usual topology. Let $X$ be the set $X=(1,2) \times \Bbb Z$ and $B=\left \{ (x,0): 1<x<2 \right \}$. Prove that $B$ is open and closed in $X$.

My solution is: since $X= \emptyset$ we have that $B$ is closed, because $B^c=\emptyset$ in $X$ , which is open (and closed). But $B$ is also open in $X$ because $B^c$ is closed in $X$.

Does my reasoning make sense?

Comment: What do you mean by ``since $X = \emptyset$''??

Comment: isn't $X$ the empty set? Open segment $(1,2)$ cartesian product $\Bbb Z$...I can't see any nonempty set..

Comment: Or maybe not, just open segment times the vertical lines through $\Bbb Z$

Comment: What does $(1,2)\times\Bbb Z$ *mean*?

Comment: @Matheman: If you like, $X = \{x, y \in \Bbb R^2 : 1 < x < 2, y \in \Bbb Z\}$. $X$ is the product of nonempty subsets of $\Bbb R$, so it's definitely not empty! Particularly, all of $B$ is contained in $X$. In words, $X$ is the "open line segments" between the points $(1, n)$ and $(2, n)$ for all integers $n$.

Comment: it means the cartesian product between the open interval (1,2) on the $x$-axis and the set of the integer numbers. For example, $(1,2) \times \Bbb R$ is a vertical strip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you misunderstood the definitions - $X$ is not the empty, it is the subset of $\Bbb{R}^2$ of all ordered pairs $(x,y)$ such that $x\in (1,2)$ (i.e. $1<x<2$) and $y\in \mathbb{Z}$. Now, $B$ is the subset of $X$ of all ordered pairs $(x,y)$ such that $1<x<2$ and $y=0$. In other words, $B=(1,2)\times \{0\}$. Since $(1,2)$ is open in $(1,2)$ and $\{0\}$ is open in $\mathbb{Z}$, $B=(1,2)\times \{0\}$ is open in $X=(1,2)\times \mathbb{Z}$. On the other hand, the complement of $B$ is  $B^c=(1,2)\times (\mathbb{Z}\setminus\{0\})$; again, since $(1,2)$ is open in $(1,2)$ and $\mathbb{Z}\setminus\{0\}$ is open in $\mathbb{Z}$, we get that $B^c=(1,2)\times (\mathbb{Z}\setminus\{0\})$ is open in $X$, and hence $B$ is closed in $X$.

Is that clearer now?

Comment: I'm sorry but don't remember why $\{0\}$ and $\Bbb Z \setminus \{0\}$ are both open in $\Bbb Z$.

Comment: $\Bbb{Z}$ has the topology induced as a subset of $\mathbb{R}$. Now, $(-0.5,0.5)$ is open in  $\mathbb{R}$, and $\{0\}=(-0.5,0.5)\cap \mathbb{Z}$. So $\{0\}$ is open in $\mathbb{Z}$. Similairly, $\{n\}$ is open in $\mathbb{Z}$ for every $n\in\mathbb{Z}$, and therefore $\mathbb{Z}\setminus\{0\}=\bigcup_{n\neq 0}\{n\}$ is also open (as well as every other subset of $\mathbb{Z}$).

Comment: Understood. thanks!

Comment: Great, you're welcome!